# Single inheritance causes TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance

I'm trying to make subclasses of a Command class but I keep getting the error:

> metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a
>   (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases

```
class Command(object):
  def __init__(self, sock, str):
    self.sock = sock
    self.str = str
  def execute(self):
    pass

from src import Command

class BroadcastCommand(object, Command):
  def __init__(self, sock, str):
    super(Command, self).__init__()
  def execute(self):
    self.broadcast()
  def broadcast(self):
    print(str)
```

My Command.py file and BroadcastCommand.py file are currently in the same package directory.

Comment: That's not the error message that would result from the code you've posted.

Comment: Why do you subclass `object` in `BroadcastCommand`? That will always be a problem because it messes up the MRO.

Answer (score 0):

If `Command` inherits from `object` then there's no use making `BroadcastCommand` inheriting from both `object` and `Command` - it's enough that it inherits from `Command` -, and it indeed raises the `TypeError` you get. Solution: make `BroadcastCommand` inherit from `Command` only.

As a side note, your `super` call should be

```
super(BroadcastCommand, self).__init__(sock, str)
```

and naming your param `str` is possibly not a good idea.

Comment: The OP's `super()` call can be reduced down to `super().__init__(sock, str)` since Python 3 allows you to call `super()` without arguments - only inside a class definition that is.